# Synchronize figures movement in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, window-resize

Consider the following code which creates a simple GUI with an axes and a pushbutton (you can copy/paste directly in Matlab).

```
function DummyGUI

global hFig hNewFig
ScreenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');

hFig = figure('Visible','off','Position',[ScreenSize(3)/2,ScreenSize(4)/2,450,285],'ResizeFcn',@CheckPosition);
MyImage = imread('peppers.png');

hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Push here',...
    'Position',[315,220,70,25],'Callback',@hButton_Callback);

hAxes = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[50,60,200,185]); 

set(hFig,'Visible','on')

    function hButton_Callback(~,~)   % pushbutton callback   

        imshow(MyImage,'Parent',hAxes);           

        FigPos = get(hFig,'Position');
        hNewFig = figure('Position',[FigPos(1)-450 FigPos(2)+100 350 200]); % Place new figure ~ at top left of 1st one.

        imshow(rgb2gray(MyImage),'Parent',gca) % display some image

    end

    function CheckPosition(~,~) % ResizeFcn callback. Get 1st figure position and update 2nd figure.

        hFigNewPos = get(hFig,'Position'); % Get position/size
        set(hNewFig,'Position',[hFigNewPos(1)-250 hFigNewPos(2)+100 hFigNewPos(3) hFigNewPos(4)]);

    end
end
```

Pressing the pushbutton makes an image display in the axes and opens another figure right beside the first one.

**My question is this**: How can we synchronize the movement of the second figure relatively to the first one (~ top left) so that it always stays at the same position wherever the first one is moved?

As you can see my attempt at doing this was to add a callback for the `ResizeFcn`, and the 2nd figure actually resizes simultaneously with the first one as I would expect, however it does not move on the screen at all and I don't see why. Of course this example is very simple but I'd like to expand it to more complex GUIs/more figures.

Thanks!

Comment: According to Yair Altman, a callback for something like that is not (directly) available. You can use Java callbacks instead: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks.

Comment: thanks for the link! I should have looked at Yair's website but I was pretty sure it could be done without Java callbacks.